# Как передать значение из одного стейта в другой?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

Как я могу значение из этого стейта передать в тот, который идет за ним? И почему `print` выдает `FSMContextProxy state = <default>, data = {}, closed = True`, если стейт еще активен?

```py
@dp.message_handler(state=fs.waiting_for_name, content_types=types.ContentTypes.TEXT)
async def get_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if len(message.text) < 1:
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы ввели недопустимое имя, попробуйте еще')
    else:
        await state.finish()
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите возраст')
        await fs.waiting_for_age.set()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создаешь функцию или message_handler

```
@dp.message_handler(state = fs.waiting_for_age)
async def get_age(message: types.Message, state: FSMcontext):
  async with state.proxy() as data:
    data['age'] = message.text
#Дальше сам
```

Здесь хорошо все расказано
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O_pPNlXMzsw&list=PLwVBSkoL97Q3phZRyInbM4lShvS1cBl-U&index=7&t=369s

Comment: У меня не хватает репутации и я не могу прокомментировать вопрос, но прокомментирую под ответом. Не ```message.chat.id```, а ```message.from_user.id```